# Can't use segue more than once

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios8

I'm trying to see a different viewcontroller whenever my app gets a push notification. I tried to use

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"shootPicture" sender:self];
```

and

```
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:) withObject:@"shootPicture" waitUntilDone:NO];
```

and

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    UIViewController *BombaViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"BombaViewController"];
    [self presentViewController:BombaViewController animated:NO completion:NULL];
```

All af the above example works, but they work JUST ONCE! After the viewcontroller goes back to the main tabbed controller, it doesn't work anymore.

I've also used NSLog to make sure that the system can actually intercept the push notifications. 
Any suggestions?

Comment: How are you going back?

Comment: I just put a button and dragged it to the starting Tabcontroller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I just put a button and dragged it to the starting Tabcontroller

This would indicate you have a new push / modal segue.

So, you aren't really going back, you're going to a new copy of your tab controller which is sitting in front of everything else. What you should really be doing is unwinding the segue that got you there, or connecting the button to an action in your code and calling `dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:`.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH KIND STRANGER! I couldn't wrap my head around this, Thanks again! :)